# How to calculate min width for a circle using stored procedure

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql

I tried  to display the percentage of my result in a bubble.

I have used this below stored procedure to set the css style (width, height, font-size to show it as a bubble) for the div which is bound inside a datalist.

```
Select 
    *,
    'width: '+cast(@maxWidth*(CountItemPercentage/100) as varchar(max)) +'px; height: '+cast(@maxWidth*(CountItemPercentage/100) as varchar(max)) +'px; font-size: '+cast(@maxWidth*((CountItemPercentage/100)/5) as varchar(max)) +'px;' as CSSStyle
from 
    @temp
```

I have set the maximum width to be 300px.

Now my problem is, if the percentage is below 10% the bubble is too small to see. How to set min width for div using store procedure to make it clearly visible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but CSS has also the "min-width: 50px;" property

Comment: Code looks a bit weird, but logically, I think you want something like `Math.Max(calculatedWidth, @maxWidth / 10)`, which returns the bigger one of the two.

Comment: Unless you have some crazy constraint, I would strongly suggest simply returning the `CountItemPercentage` to the web tier, and using either your web technology or javascript to set the style. Putting UI logic in the data layer goes against the separation of concerns principle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're doing things like that, but I believe that every client/project has his needs. Beside that you can use a CASE statement like this:

```
--Set the minimum width percentage DECLARE @MinWidthPercentage as int; set @MinWidthPercentage = 10;

SELECT (CASE
    WHEN CountItemPercentage < @MinWidthPercentage THEN 'width: ' + cast(@maxWidth*(MinWidthPercentage /100) as varchar(max)) + 'px; height: ' + cast(@maxWidth*(MinWidthPercentage /100) as varchar(max))
+ 'px; font-size: ' + cast(@maxWidth*((MinWidthPercentage /100)/5) as varchar(max)) +'px;'
    ELSE 'width: '+cast(@maxWidth*(CountItemPercentage/100) as varchar(max)) +'px; height: '+cast(@maxWidth*(CountItemPercentage/100) as varchar(max)) +'px; font-size: '+cast(@maxWidth*((CountItemPercentage/100)/5) as varchar(max))
+'px;') AS CSSStyle  from @temp
```

Or you can use an if at the beginning to set a @percentage variable and use that variable instead of the CountItemPercentage.